# SQL case statement taking aliased names value

Tags: sql, oracle

In this sql query I need to get how many of one car a person has bought and label them into first, second or frequent buyer **with only one select statement**. I am trying to use a CASE statement for this.

```
SELECT custname, COUNT(carserial) as "Cars bought",
    CASE "Cars bought"
        WHEN "Cars bought" = 1
            THEN "One time buyer"
        WHEN "Cars bought" = 2
            THEN "two time buyer"
        WHEN "Cars bought" >= 3
            THEN "frequent buyer"
    END
FROM SI.car
WHERE carmake = 'MERCEDES'
GROUP BY custname
```

I get an error the the first when statement under the = statement

```
WHEN "Cars bought" = 1
```

I'm assuming it is something to do with the aliased name.

Comment: This is question on my assignment and I am told specifically to use one select statement. I have also tried moving the CASE to after the group by in an order by statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the quotes by converting them to single quotes, and use aggregation per each conditional expression rather than the alias (`"Cars bought"`) within the current case

```
SELECT custname,
       COUNT(carserial) AS "Cars bought",
       CASE WHEN COUNT(carserial) = 1 THEN
                 'One time buyer'
            WHEN COUNT(carserial) = 2 THEN
                 'Twice buyer' 
            WHEN COUNT(carserial) >= 3 THEN
                 'Frequent buyer'
            END
  FROM SI.car
 WHERE carmake = 'MERCEDES'
 GROUP BY custname
```

Answer (score 0):

On second thoughts, it should be working.

```
CASE COUNT(carserial) WHEN 1 THEN 'one' 
     WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'three or more' END AS buyertype
```

What is the exact error you get?

Comment: The exact error I get is: _ORA-00904: "frequent buyer": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 18_ I have also updated my code to what you have suggested `SELECT custname, COUNT(carserial) as "Cars bought",
CASE COUNT(carserial)
        WHEN 1
            THEN "One time buyer"
        WHEN 2
            THEN "two time buyer"
        ELSE "frequent buyer"
END as "buyertype"
FROM SI.car
WHERE carmake = 'MERCEDES'
GROUP BY custname`

Comment: Ah, no. I had suggested single quotes by habit, had not even noticed you used double quotes. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I believe a good way to run this query with just one SELECT is:

```
SELECT 
    custname, 
    COUNT(carserial) as cars_bought,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(carserial) = 1
            THEN "One time buyer"
        WHEN COUNT(carserial) = 2
            THEN "Two times buyer"
        WHEN COUNT(carserial) >= 3
            THEN "Frequent buyer"
    END as client_type
FROM SI.car
WHERE carmake = 'MERCEDES'
GROUP BY custname
```

Comment: Running this I still get an error now in a different spot _ORA-00904: "Frequent buyer": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 18_

Comment: Probably my code is in a different dialect from yours. Try this one instead: *select
  CUSTNAME,
  count(CARSERIAL) CARS_BOUGHT,
  case
    when count(CARSERIAL) = 1 then "One time buyer"
    when count(CARSERIAL) = 2 then "Two times buyer"
    when count(CARSERIAL) >= 3 then "Frequent buyer"
  end CLIENT_TYPE
from SI. CAR
where CARMAKE = 'MERCEDES'
group by CUSTNAME*

Comment: You could also use this website for SQL dialect translation: https://www.jooq.org/translate/

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT custname, "Cars bought",
    CASE "Cars bought"
        WHEN "Cars bought" = 1
            THEN "One time buyer"
        WHEN "Cars bought" = 2
            THEN "two time buyer"
        WHEN "Cars bought" >= 3
            THEN "frequent buyer"
    END
FROM
(
  SELECT custname, COUNT(carserial) as "Cars bought",
  FROM SI.car
  WHERE carmake = 'MERCEDES'
  GROUP BY custname
) dt
```

Comment: Yes this would work if I wasn't under the constraint of only being able to use a single select statement. Might just take the loss in marks and use this If I cannot figure it out. Thank you